# How to configure memory mapped settings for embedded neo4j 2.0.1?

Tags: java, performance, memory-mapping, neo4j

The Neo4j manual refers to properties as:

```
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=
```

I guessed these mapped to the following Java API:

```
GraphDatabaseSettings.nodestore_mapped_memory_size
GraphDatabaseSettings.relationshipstore_mapped_memory_size
GraphDatabaseSettings.mapped_memory_page_size
GraphDatabaseSettings.strings_mapped_memory_size
GraphDatabaseSettings.arrays_mapped_memory_size
```

Can someone confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is correct. see https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/master/community/kernel/src/main/java/org/neo4j/graphdb/factory/GraphDatabaseSettings.java#L190 for the full details.